# Error when submitting a form with two different models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, model-view-controller

I have an `office` model which is a list of all the current offices. I also have a `calendar` model which will just act as a company calendar. I am trying to get a dropdown of all the current offices to display on the `localhost:3000/calendars/new` so people can see where the event will be taking place. When I go to submit the form, I get the error shown below. I have posted all relevant code as well. Thanks in advance.

Calendar.rb:

```
class Calendar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :office
end
```

Office.rb:

```
class Office < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :calendars
end
```

calendars_controller:

```
def new
  @calendar = Calendar.new
  @offices = Office.all
end
```

_form.html.erb:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :office_id, class: "general-text-label" %><br>
  <%= collection_select :calendar, :office, @offices, :id, :name, {include_blank: true}, {class: "selectize"} %>
</div>
```

Error:

[image]

Parameters:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"lNP3u+Hs2FYsTBTClWuwJWiwW8HTFECzGVD4CdEOgOF5WD2eNiMNHtQuHjHpynJp7CaIDio09/mhvQg5rLhgtA==", "calendar"=>{"name"=>"Listing Agent Workshop", "description"=>"ffhfh", "date"=>"Friday Feb 17, 2017", "time"=>"4:00 PM", "office"=>"2"}, "commit"=>"Save"}
```

Comment: can you post the parameters that reach your server. You can check that on the console running the rails server (`rails s`)

Comment: @AbhishekKumar Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"lNP3u+Hs2FYsTBTClWuwJWiwW8HTFECzGVD4CdEOgOF5WD2eNiMNHtQuHjHpynJp7CaIDio09/mhvQg5rLhgtA==", "calendar"=>{"name"=>"Listing Agent Workshop", "description"=>"ffhfh", "date"=>"Friday Feb 17, 2017", "time"=>"4:00 PM", "office"=>"2"}, "commit"=>"Save"}

Comment: @AbhishekKumar All of that is correct so I'm not sure where I am going wrong.

Comment: That's your error, you're passing `office => 2`, and your Calendar object wants ant Office object or and office_id.

Comment: @Anthony But 2 is the office id...so I'm a bit lost.

Comment: it wants `Calendar.new(office: Offind.find(calendar_params[:office]), other_params_here)` OR it wants `Calendar.new(office_id: calendar_params[:office_id])`.

Comment: @Anthony Gotcha. Add it as an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails is trying to infer which `Office` to associate with your new `Calendar`.  Your calendar is being built as:

```
Calendar.new({"name"=>"Listing Agent Workshop", "description"=>"ffhfh", "date"=>"Friday Feb 17, 2017", "time"=>"4:00 PM", "office"=>"2"})
```

Rails knows the `office` key is an associated model but it expect the value to be an actual instance of an `Office`, instead here it's just a string.

Instead, you should either specify the id and let rails look it up or find the object first if that is a concern.

First way (change the params):

```
Calendar.new({"name"=>"Listing Agent Workshop", "description"=>"ffhfh", "date"=>"Friday Feb 17, 2017", "time"=>"4:00 PM", "office_id"=>"2"})
```

Better way:

```
office = Office.find(calendar_params[:office])
calendar_params[:office] = office
Calendar.new(calendar_params)
```